# Obtener ultimo Path final de URL en php

Tags: php, php7

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto MVC en php y necesito obtener el path de la URL que estoy ingresando de la siguiente forma:

Entradas Posibles (Ejemplos)

- .stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
- .stackoverflow.com/questions/1
- .stackoverflow.com/questions/

Resultados Deseados:

- ask
- 1
- questions

En los fines específicos que tengo solo trabajo con números, pero mas adelante tendré que trabajar con cualquier tipo de path. Para resolver mi problema rápidamente utilice esta función.

```
$vID=substr(str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), -1);
```

De esta forma elimino los "/" y obtengo el ultimo carácter. El problema es que esto solo sirve para detectar números de una sola cifra. Eliminé el "/" para poder saber que cuando obtuviera una "e" es porque estaba entrando a la ruta template/.

Necesito finalmente poder buscar la forma de obtener la ultima palabra después del ultimo "/" y en su defecto sino hay nada, que me retorne la ultima palabra antes de el.

Muchas gracias chicos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Separar la cadena por cada `/` utilizando [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)
- Eliminar los elementos vacios del arreglo obtenido utilizando [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php).
- Tomar solo el último elemento del arreglo con [`array_pop`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-pop.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```php
$valor = @array_pop(array_filter(explode('/', '.stackoverflow.com/questions/')));
echo $valor;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/130f2)</kbd>

Comment: Amigo eres un crack, claro por supuesto lo que dices tiene razón y muy practico. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Qué tal si intentas dividiendo las partes de la cadena así:

```
$url_ptr = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Y usas un condicional para el último elemento de la cadena:

```
if (end($url_ptr)==''){
    $vID = $url_ptr[count($url_ptr)-2];
} else {
    $vID = end($url_ptr);
}
```

Así, en los casos en que tengas "stackoverflow.com/questions/", toma no el último elemento del *explode* (que es un ""), sino el penúltimo, que es "questions". La función *end* toma el último elemento del array

Comment: Hola Jhan, excelente respuesta pero Marcos hizo una más legible y más eficiente. Igualmente me ganaste porque a mi no se me ocurrió usar explode. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se puede Solucionar Usando basename() // ilustrarse con la documentacion Oficial

ejemplo
stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $url;
// El Resultado seria stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

echo basename($url)
// El Resultado de usar basename seria ask;